# How detect mathquill editor to write equation

Tags: javascript, jquery, text-editor, mathquill

I am currently making rich text editor with maths equation writing.
[image]

As per above image you can see yellow marker which is `mathquill-editable` span.
and i made button with containing some maths symbols.
What I want!!
When user click button than equation should be print at cursor location.
I selected `mathquill-editable` span with class.
example `$('#classname')` for write equation from button.
Its works fine but problem comes when I add another `mathquill-editable` span.
When multiple span are there than every time when i click button than their value printed in every class at same time.
How I detect particular span is active and value will print on cursor's span only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my little efforts to find just one element from all class.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  /* when the page has loaded... */
  $('.mathquill-editable').click(function(){  /* ...bind click event to .boxSet elements */
    $('.mathquill-editable').removeClass('hilite'); /* On click, remove any 'hilite' class */
    $(this).addClass('hilite'); /* ...and add 'hilite' class to clicked element */ 
   });
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gaurangnil/toeca12j/)